# Toggle / collapse images and other parts

Tags: feature-request, images

I thinks it would be nice if we could toggle/ collapse images in a question or answer lets say I put in multiple images like this

Here is my first image

[image]

And here is a second

[image]

I could keep going here but I think you get the point

Should we have the option to collapse the images

You could even take this a step further and allow collapsing in other areas such as answers maybe an expand collapse all like you get in Gmail.

Comment: I fixed your post, and by the way, *you're welcome*

Comment: @Jeff: That's one way of fixing the typos in the images. :)

Comment: Why would you ever want to collapse unicorns? Do you have no soul?

Comment: @Jeff: Pl allow collapsing the code blocks too.

Comment: @Jeff: That's awesome I love it! @random good point but not all posts have pretty unicorns like those @yoda I know your question is not directed toward me but what is "PI"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good greasemonkey/local script.

```
$('.post-text img').each(function(i,e){
    var $img = $(this);
    $('<span>').text('Expand/Collapse Image').css({
        fontSize: '10px',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }).click(function(e){
        $img.slideToggle();
    }).after('<br>').insertBefore($img);
});
```

i.e. I personally prefer the image there, but I can see how others might want to collapse them. End result? Use a personal customization where you feel the site's lacking.

---

### UserScript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Hide/Show StackExchange Images
// @description    Adds a small (clickable) text above all images in posts, allowing you to hide/show the image.
// @namespace      bradchristie
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var jQuery = $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
(function(){
  $('.post-text img').each(function(i,e){
    var $img = $(this);
    $('<span>').text('Expand/Collapse Image').css({
      fontSize: '10px',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }).click(function(e){
      $img.slideToggle();
    }).after('<br>').insertBefore($img);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: how would I use that ?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Turn it in to a *.user.js file (and wrap it so it uses the `unsafeWindow.jQuery` found on these sites) and install it to your favorite (extensible) browser.

Comment: @mcgrailm: Updated answer; save the above code in to a `<whatever>.user.js` file on your desktop, then open that file in your browser and select install. (note: requires greasemonkey for FF or you can make it another browser plugin type).

Comment: that seems like a neat idea but I think it would be better suited to have this stuff in the sight itself IMHO maybe each user could have it in their prefs tab ?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Honestly, in the (literally) 2 minutes it took me to implement, over the (probably between post code, prefs code, prefs wire-up, database schema change, re-plumbing, etc.--16 hours worth of coding?) I think a client solution is a _lot_ better. But hey, that's just me.

Comment: @brad what doe "and wrap it so it uses the unsafeWindow.jQuery found on these sites)" this mean

Comment: @mcgrailm: Just copy the code below the divider in to a file called SO_Collapsible_Images.user.js and save it on your desktop. Then open that file with firefox and it will work, as-is (with greasemonkey plugin, of course).

Comment: i stalled this on chrome but it made it into an extension how do I click it then ?